# grep equivalent to pcre's `?` operator

Tags: regex, grep, pcre

With PCRE you'd do `ax?a` to find strings like `aa` and `axa`.

How would you write a regex for grep that'd do that?

Comment: That seemed to do the trick - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In grep, you need to escape the quantifier:

```
ax\?a
```

Answer (score 4):

grep default uses BRE, you could use `-P` (PCRE) or `-E` (ERE) option.

for example:

```
kent$  echo "aa
axa
axxxxa"|grep -E 'ax?a'
aa
axa
```

with BRE, you have to escape chars like `( ? + ...` to give them special meaning.